# Scrapy in Python order extract with xpaths

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm **scraping** some text from a page with a spider in Python and the output is a .csv file. Everything it's ok except the order of some records, it generates in different order in the .csv file that what I put in the spider.py:

This is what I get:

[image: ![enter image description here]

But this is the order that I need and that I pass into the spider.py (the rows with colors are inverted):

[image]

I don't know why it don't respect the order of the data **scraped**. For some reason it respect the same order that the data appears in the webpage, but if I pass it in different order than the web ¿why the spider ignores me?

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem

class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'verbos'
allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
print("Ingrese un verbo:")
variable = input()
start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]


def parse(self, response):

    eu = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    voce = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    nos = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()  | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()
    voces = response.xpath('//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text()  | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text() | //*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract()

    for item in zip(eu, voce, nos, voces):
        scraped_info = {
            'eu' : item[0],
            'voce' : item[1],
            'nos' : item[2],
            'voces' : item[3],
        }

        yield scraped_info
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy


class MercadoItem(scrapy.Item):
eu = scrapy.Field()
voce = scrapy.Field()
nos = scrapy.Field()
voces  = scrapy.Field()
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'verbos'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['verbos.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'verbos.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'verbos.pipelines.MercadoPipeline': 500}
FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = 'verbos_items.csv'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='cp1252'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath expressions only determine matches, not order.

Instead of using a single XPath expression, iterate each XPath expression in the desired order in a loop.

So, change:

```py
words = response.xpath('xpath1 | xpath2').getall()
for word in words:
    yield {'word': word}
```

To:

```
for xpath in ('xpath1', 'xpath2'):
    words = response.xpath(xpath).getall()
    for word in words:
        yield {'word': word}
```

Comment: I tried only for the "eu" column and that works! now I get it in the order what I want, but how can I do it adding the others 3 columns also? I can edit the code if you need it

Comment: You could use a tuple of tuples of xpaths instead of a tuple in the outer `for` loop. Or if the XPath expressions follow a pattern, you could make it more simple using string formatting. But now that you understand why it was not working as expected, you should be able to figure out how to make it work.